# device notification program in c

Tags: c, winapi

i write this code in c for detecting a flash in win xp 32
but it doesn't do anything
can anyone help
( i want just understand when a flash insert then run another program but i need a wndmain an a wndproc that i can't write them correct)
and the last question is it possible that it does't work because i run it in win 7 64bit????

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    hInstance =(HINSTANCE)(GetModuleHandle(NULL));
    if(WndProc)
    {

    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0 )
    {
         TranslateMessage(&msg);
          DispatchMessage(&msg);
          printf("%s" , msg);
    }

    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uiMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uiMsg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("WM_DEVICECHANGE"), TEXT("WndProc"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uiMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get away with creating an instance of a pre-defined window type, followed by sub-classing it (setting it's window procedure to be one that you've written) That would give a shorter code than the one I present. You should note that the MSDN code you've linked to only provides a *code snippet*, that is to say - it's an incomplete program. You still need to have a mechanism by which you receive messages from windows.

Here's a program that will catch insert and remove messages, under win7, compiled with minGW. It's just 13 lines added to a Win32 Gui (Frame App) template inside code::blocks.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>

//  Declare Windows procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//  Make the class name into a global variable
char szClassName[ ] = "CodeBlocksWindowsApp";

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               // This is the handle for our window
    MSG messages;            // Here messages to the application are saved
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        // Data structure for the windowclass

    // The Window structure
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Code::Blocks Template Windows App",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );

    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UINT event;

    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
            event = (UINT)wParam;
            switch (event)
            {
                case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Device arrival", "Notice", MB_ICONASTERISK);
                    break;

                case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
                    MessageBox(NULL, "Device removal", "Notice", MB_ICONASTERISK);
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Use the following WindowProcedure with the MSDN code mellodi linked to earlier. This will allow the retrieval of device name and other attributes (which I totally ignored)

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UINT event;

    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                Main_OnDeviceChange(hwnd, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1: Nice simple example (I resorted to linking elsewhere in my answer :) ).  One question - does this work despite not calling `RegisterDeviceNotification`?

Comment: thank                                                                     i copy your code and run it but it open a window that is empty and it's title is in chinis  ?????????????????????????????????

Comment: and another question in the page that i attach the code actually return  the driver name too , where should i use that part in your code?

Comment: @icabod - thanks. Yes, on my system it does work - win7 home pro.

Comment: @mellodi - I'll update the code sample. You can see, when I get a WM_DEVICECHANGED message, I simply call the code that you linked to earlier. *Note:* I've only added an updated WindowProcedure, you stil need to remove the existing one AND add the code from msdn that you linked to. :)

Comment: it like what i said , an empty window with chines title and it doesn't print the driver name in cmd

Comment: Like I said (1) You still need to copy the code you linked to into the code I posted. It isn't supposed to work yet - I just showed you where to call the linked code from within my code. (2) For 'chines title', you probably need to look at your character set. I'm in AUS, using a NON UNICODE build (and the locale set to UK). If you're using UNICODE, don't forget to wrap the text with the appropriate macro, e.g L() or TEXT() etc. If your title is ~ 17 chars long, it sounds like a unicode issue (i.e unicode needs 2 chars per letter, title should be ~34 chars long)

Comment: i copy that to your code but it still work the same                             what should i do? it doesn't even print the name of driver

Comment: can you please check this page it shows that i done the whole thing you said                                                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196106/device-notification-in-c-when-a-flash-insert

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a *lot* of code, such as creating a new window class that registers your WndProc function to handle dispatched messages, etc.  Unfortunately in order to be able to handle WM_ messages, you need to do quite a bit of work.

As a good starting point I would point you to Raymond Chen's [Scratch Program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/04/22/410773.aspx).  It's simple, but contains a simple framework to get you started.

If you specifically need C and not C++, then the [first version of the scratch program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/07/23/54576.aspx) should suffice.

Comment: actually i don't really need to open window, i just need to understand when a flash insert, i find this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363215(VS.85).aspx                                                    but it doesn't work whith out main function and we need a big help for writing its winmain()

Comment: The device notification is performed by a WM_DEVICECHANGE message, which needs to go to a window (even a dummy, invisible window) - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431.aspx) for information. For that to happen, you need to understand how the windows message pump works, but for the time being you can look at the scratch programs I linked to as a starting point.

Comment: ok tnx but the page that you gave is in c++ and have classes and i can't understand                                                             sry but do you have any c code too?

Comment: There is already a link there for the C version of the scratch program.